# How do I use Chrome Content-Script, match patterns on the URL's query parameters?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension, with content scripts, match only Google-Images search results pages.
They (so far as I could tell) are identified by `&tbm=isch` in the URL parameters. But, match patterns seem to work only on the path. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways:
(1) You can use [the `include_globs` property in the manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs). Something like this should work:

```js
{
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "exclude_globs":    [  ],
        "include_globs":    [ "https://www.google.com/search*tbm=isch*" ],
        "js":               [ "YOUR_SCRIPT.user.js" ],
        "matches":          [ "https://www.google.com/search*"
                            ]
    } ],
    ... ...
```

(2) You could place a test like this at the top of your content script:

```js
if ( ! /\btbm=isch\b/i.test (location.search) ) {
    return;
}
```

---

The former is probably more efficient, but may be harder to tune.
You could also use a combination of the methods.

Comment: Hmm, second option is what I ended up doing and it works, but I tested the first just to see if it worked but I still got the test `alert()` on google.com (textual search).

Comment: Odd, it works for me. Post your exact manifest and the URL that triggered the extra run.

Comment: It must've been some random thing I was doing wrong. It worked :) Thanks!

Comment: Suppose I need to match a url that begins with www.google.com, no matter what comes after it(path or query parameters). In this case, what is to be done?

Comment: @JophinJoseph, that's just a simple: `"matches": [ "http://www.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*" ]`.

Comment: I had tried that earlier but was not able to get the desired response because of an error in the content script itself. It was working fine earlier itself. Thank you @BrockAdams.

Comment: @JophinJoseph, ask a new question, if you need to. And upvote.